# How to update value and then return back the updated value only if it was really updated?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to improve SQL for our SaaS which supports user cash balance. When user makes an order, the order price should be subtracted from his balance.

The subtraction must only be done if the user has enough balance. If the subtraction is done, the query should return the NEW balance, or NULL if failed to update because not enough balance.

For now I achieved this query:

```
update usr_account_balance
set balance      = @new_balance := balance - AMOUNT_TO_SUBTRACT,
    last_updated = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
where user_id = 221
  and balance >= AMOUNT_TO_SUBTRACT;
select @new_balance;
```

The problem with this code is that it will return the balance regardless if it was updated or not. But I'd like to return NULL if nothing was updated in previous query, so I can warn user that his order couldn't proceed because not enough balance available.

EDIT 1:
The SaaS is running on PHP, wordpress backend.

Comment: On which programming language  and or which framework is your SaaS running

Comment: It is running on PHP, wordpress backend.

Answer (score 0):

The query should gove you the wanted result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE usr_account_balance (user_id int,balance DECIMAL (10,2),last_updated timestamp )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO usr_account_balance VALUES(221, 8.0,now())
> ```

> ```
> update usr_account_balance
> set balance      = IF(balance >= 10,@new_balance := balance - 10, @new_balance := balance),
>     last_updated = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
> where user_id = 221
>   and balance >= 10;
> select @new_balance;
> ```

> ```
> | @new_balance |
> | :----------- |
> | null         |
> ```

> ```
> update usr_account_balance
> set balance      = IF(balance >= 7,@new_balance := balance - 7, @new_balance := balance),
>     last_updated = UTC_TIMESTAMP()
> where user_id = 221
>   and balance >= 7;
> select @new_balance;
> ```

> ```
> | @new_balance |
> | -----------: |
> |         1.00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a81ec31a3fcc9ee6fe23f2eac456c212)*